# nvim finds the function but vim does not

Tags: vim, neovim

I am using a `vim`/`nvim` plugin [asyncrun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) that enables an [API call](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) that works fine in `nvim` if I implement it in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` using a line:

```
call asyncrun#run("", "cwd", "firefox")
```

Now this same line does not work for `vim` if I try to use it inside `~/.vimrc`. I always get a warning:

```
Unknown finction: asyncrun#run
```

What needs to be changed in order for this to also work for `vim`?

---

Following the @doopNudles comment I also clarify that `vim` plugin is manually installed in the folder `~/.vim/pack/my-plugins/start/vim-asyncrun/asyncrun.vim/plugin/asyncrun.vim`. I install all my `vim` plugins the same way *(using the `vim` v8 native ability to detect plugins)*.

Comment: Where is the plugin installed?

Comment: `vim` plugin is inside a folder `~/.vim/pack/my-plugins/start/vim-asyncrun/asyncrun.vim/plugin/asyncrun.vim`. It is using the same folder structure as any other `vim` plugins that I use and they work. Also check the extended question.

Comment: The problem was that `~/.vim/pack/my-plugins/start/vim-asyncrun/asyncrun.vim/plugin/asyncrun.vim` has one extra folder! It works if I delete the extra folder (`asyncrun.vim`) like this `~/.vim/pack/my-plugins/start/vim-asyncrun/plugin/asyncrun.vim`

Comment: @71GA make it an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `~/.vim/pack/my-plugins/start/vim-asyncrun/asyncrun.vim/plugin/asyncrun.vim` has one extra folder!

It works if I delete the extra folder `asyncrun.vim` like this `~/.vim/pack/my-plugins/start/vim-asyncrun/plugin/asyncrun.vim`